# I'm not able to delete the local folder after unshelving the shleve set in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I have created a shelve set by deleting a folder. But this shelve set deleted the folder on TFS. I want my shelve set to delete the folder on local system if I unshelve the shleve set.

Comment: Are you able to see `delete` pending changes on the folder after you unshelve the shleveset? I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side. Could you please provide detailed steps you have done? In addition, which version of TFS do you use?

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: After deep investigation, I found out that after building sencha(as the folder belongs to a Sencha project), it adds some other files. The files that were present on TFS got deleted but those generated by Sencha were not.

Comment: Have you found the root cause? Are the new generated files checked in to TFS yet? Could you please provide detailed steps you have done so that I can reproduce your issue?